# android OnEditorActionListener not working with custom soft keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

i'm working on a project wich require the use of a custom soft keyboard developed by some one else. The problem is that the setOnEditorActionListener does not work in a specific windows where a fragment is used. Does not work means that the onEditorAction is not fired at all. The problem appens only with the custom keyboard, with the default one every thing is working well. The problem is that the soft keyboard project is very complex because i don't know soft keyboard logics and I need to solve the problem before tomoroow morning. Does anyone have an idea of this behavior? Please help

this is the part where i set the listener, this code is working all around the project but here, even the first listener's line is not reached

```
((EditText) getView().findViewById(R.seatDetailCommonHeader.txtName)).setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
                        if (event != null && event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                            return true;
                        }


                        // KeyboardHelper.setKeyboardVisibilty(v, false);
                        executeCheck();

                        return true;

                    }
                });
```

i went into further investigations, i put a breakpoint on every method's first line in the keyboard code (which is the one taken from the sdk samples with just some layout modification) and the same EditText in two different activities fires different methods:

in one case (the working one) this methods are fired when action button is clicked:

```
LatinKeyboard.isInside
LatinKeyboard.isInside
LatinKeyboard.isInside
LatinKeyboard.isInside
LatinKeyboard.isInside
LatinKeyboard.isInside
LatinKeyboard.isInside
LatinKeyboard.isInside
LatinKeyboard.isInside
SoftKeyboard.onKey
SoftKeyboard.isWordSeparator
SoftKeyboard.sendKey
SoftKeyboard.keyDownUp
SoftKeyboard.keyDownUp
SoftKeyboard.updateShiftKeyState
```

in the other case (the one that is not working) the same methods are fired, plus these:

```
SoftKeyboard.onFinishInput
SoftKeyboard.onStartInput
SoftKeyboard.updateShiftKeyState
LatinKeyboard.setImeOptions
SoftKeyboard.onStartInputView
```

hope someone has some idea of this behavior because i'm really in trouble

Comment: @SimonVeloper have you solved the issue..